# Where does Skype store local chats?

Tags: macos, skype

I've searched the entire internet, but it seems nobody could figure out where the latest versions of Skype stores local chats.

OS: macOS High Sierra

Skype Version: 8.54.0.91

Information on internet is outdated and I think the file "main.db" doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Since Skype 8.41 chat history is stored in the cloud and not locally. There have been lots of complaints about this. See for example [Retain all chat history locally (regardless of the cloud), like Skype 7 – Customer Feedback for Skype](https://skype.uservoice.com/forums/914527-welcome-to-skype-ideas/suggestions/35074018-retain-all-chat-history-locally-regardless-of-the?page=1&per_page=20)